# How to resolve error when trying to use mongodumb and -o/--out flag

Tags: mongodb, mongodump

I get the following error when I try to specify an output directory, how do I resolve this. According to the documentation, I think I'm doing everything right?

Command:

```
mongodump --db studioenterprise -o C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Dumps
```

Error:

```
2023-02-27T19:26:20.786-0600    error parsing command line options: error parsing positional arguments: provide only one MongoDB connection string. Connection strings must begin with mongodb:// or mongodb+srv:// schemes
2023-02-27T19:26:20.788-0600    try 'mongodump --help' for more information
```

I just downloaded and installed MongoDB tools.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What does “too many positional options” mean when doing a mongorestore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20714698/what-does-too-many-positional-options-mean-when-doing-a-mongorestore)

Comment: Try `-o "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Dumps"`, however "C:\Program Files\..." might be a poor place for database dumps

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit the default location of `C:\Windows\System32\bin\dumps` is even worst.

Comment: Maybe `%LOCALAPPDATA%` or `%TEMP%`?

Comment: I found the default location, but the answer below resolved my issue. I can now send the dump files to wherever I want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to https://www.mongodb.com/docs/database-tools/mongodump/#std-option-mongodump.--uri, the URI may be provided as a positional parameter.

Furthemore, the `--db` and `-o` option values has to be passed with '=' as `--db=studioenterprise` and `-o=C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Dumps` otherwise, it will be considered as URI parameter.

So the command looks like (assuming you have the mondogb instance running on localhost:27017):

`mongodump --db=studioenterprise -o="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Dumps"`

Comment: My instance is indeed at localhost:27017, tried your suggestion, commanded executed with no errors and did nothing.

Comment: Correction: It worked perfectly, I forgot I had dropped that database. Tested it with a different db name and it works. Thanks!